# Linking two models in django automatically

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a problem with trying to link two models together in a Django project. I have two models, Songs and Albums where the Song must be linked to an album using a Foreign-Key-Field. Adding an album works perfectly and each album has a different primary key, the way a user of my website adds a song is by going onto the album page (called detail.html) where there is a button saying 'add song' that takes the user to a forum to add the song. Currently if I add in a Foreign Key Field into the song model it allows the user to choose any album to add the song into which I do not want, I would like the song to be automatically linked to the album with the primary key of the album on the detail. Please help if you can and if anything does not make sense or you need some of the code pease reply and let me know. Thank You.

Comment: Can you share the current view that handles adding it to an album? It is likely easier to start from the existing implementation.

Comment: Have you considered storing the primary key value while redirecting and saving it with the object?. In this case essentially sending the album id and linking it to the song.

Comment: The form that adds the song shouldn't give the user an option to set an album. You could pass info about the correct album through a hidden input in the form, or find some other way to pass that info through the request.

Comment: @Ben: well often it is simply encoded in the URL. This is imho a "cleaner" way. After all, you do not per se want to hide this, and using hidden elements is no "inacessible" for the user.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem here is a link to a github i have made with some of my code, please contact me if you need me to upload more: https://github.com/aClark228/WebsiteWithDjango

Comment: @SamayGupta that is what I thought I could do I am just unable to implement it. If you have any ideas for what I could do please let me know. Here is the GitHib I have made with my code: https://github.com/aClark228/WebsiteWithDjango

Comment: @Ben I have removed the option for the user to choose what album the song is in and will try passing the information through the url again but tried it before and it didnt seem to work.